# Angular 2 , passing an id to component

Tags: angular

I am surprised on how difficult it is to just pass an id to a component. Im sure I'm missing something but essentially ALL i want to do is be able to pass an id to a nested component.
I have a parent container where my view consists of this, i am want to instantiate the 'asset' component with groupID = 6 :

```
template: `
    <div class='another_page'></div>
    <asset-manager [groupId]="6"></asset-manager>
     <div class='another_page'></div>
    `
```

I must have tried a half dozen ways based on various docs on the internet to no avail.
Here is a cut from the actual AssetManager component

```
export class AssetManager implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
@Input() groupId: string;
...
 constructor( ) {
    **this.groupID is always undefined**

}
```

Can it be this difficult ? Thanks!

Comment: Usage: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Comment: Did it work without brackets?

Comment: [groupId]=" '6' " or simply groupId="6"

Comment: yes it worked without brackets.

Comment: @Gary: the link after Usage: no longer works. I'm not sure what it was pointing to, so not sure where it should go in new documentation.

Comment: Just search for @Input. The link has been archived here is the new link. https://angular.io/api/core/Input Remember, Input might not be available in constructor. Use OnInit or AfterviewInit lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a matter of the angular 2 lifecyle, which occur in the following order, according to the "new" [lifecycle hooks documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) and [this older cheatsheet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/283526591685cc2662d797dccffc578aa93b9efa/modules/angular2/docs/cheatsheet/lifecycle%20hooks.md).

```
constructor
ngOnChanges
ngOnInit
ngDoCheck
ngAfterContentInit
ngAfterContentChecked
ngAfterViewInit
ngAfterViewChecked
ngOnDestroy
```

The constructor will always be called BEFORE inputs are available.  If you attempt to access an input property from the constructor, the value will always be undefined.

The first time that input properties are processed is during `ngOnChanges` and you could move your logic there, although the content of the template and the child views will not have been processed yet.  However, the issue here is that it will be called every time the input properties change, which may be undesirable if you want to set once.

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.groupId);
}
```

A common solution to this problem is to move input-dependent logic to `ngOnInit`, since it is called after input properties are initialized and after `ngOnChanges` has run.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.groupId);
}
```

Once you move the check for `this.groupId` to `ngOnInit`, the input property will be properly hydrated.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRuDOXYRvU9gxkUTYrE0?p=preview).  The constructor will always return `undefined` and the ngOnInit hook properly returns `6`.

In regards to the discussion in the comments, I want to modify my original understanding.  Input properties ARE indeed available before the content is rendered, since that happens after `ngOnInit` and before `ngAfterContentInit`, per the cheatsheet and new lifecycle hooks documentation:

> Called after ngOnInit when the component's or directive's content has
>   been initialized.

Comment: Thanks David.  For my first comment, I suppose I should have asked a question instead: in regard to lifecycle hooks ngOnChanges(), ngOnInit(), and ngAfterViewInit(), do you known when the view/template is processed/initialized?  I believe the first time ngOnChanges() is called, it is called before the view is processed/initialized, but I don't know that for sure.  It sounds like you think ngOnInit() is called after the view is processed/initialized -- do you know that for sure?  or do you have any references/documentation about the processing order?  (I haven't been able to find any.)

Comment: Well, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html defines the order, but it is not clear when the view is actually processed.

Comment: @MarkRajcok see my update.  I think I finally found some documentation that clears it up for me and hopefully will for you as well.  Thanks for the great questions :)

Comment: In the few short days since we've discussed this, the [Lifecyle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) dev guide page has been greatly expanded.

Comment: @MarkRajcok talk about a documentation update!  I've updated my answer to include the new link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
template: `
  <div class='another_page'></div>
  <asset-manager groupId="6"></asset-manager>
   <div class='another_page'></div>
  `
```

or

```
template: `
  <div class='another_page'></div>
  <asset-manager [groupId]="'6'"></asset-manager>
   <div class='another_page'></div>
  `
```

With [...], you try to evaluate an expression. In your case, the expression is `6` but this doesn't correspond to something, so it's undefined.

**Edit**

Following the Mark's comment, the actual problem is that the values aren't  available (undefined) in the constructor but will be in the `ngOnInit` hook...

Comment: "the expression is `6` but this doesn't correspond to something" -- Note that `6` is something, and it is a valid Angular template expression. It is the number 6 rather than the string `6`.  `[groupId]="6"` will assign the number 6 to input property `groupId`.  (Since the OP indicated a string was desired, using  `[groupId]=" '6' "` as you suggested will fix that problem -- the string `6` will be assigned instead.  However, since `groupId` is likely numeric, I have to wonder why the OP doesn't prefer a number.)